# Using OneNote Api with O365

Tags: onenote

I'm confused by the preliminary documentation on the OneNote dev blog. Does it mean that a Native App accessing has to use (compile in) a Client ID **specific** to an individual O365 subscription?

The implication being that an Commercial App would need recompiling for each different O365 customer. Is this the intention? 
If so then this severely limits the utility of OneNote Api in O365.

I'm hoping that I've misunderstood, can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 3):

Paul,
Apologies if we confused you with our initial preliminary docs.  Definitely not the case.  The app ID is relative to the O365 tenant that *publishes* the app, but you just flip over the switch to say it is a multi-tenant app for it to be able to be *consumed* by any tenant.